# Dockerfileにてsedエラー generated: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, sed

以下のDockerfileを作成しているのですが、`docker build -t notebook`を実行すると
19行目のNotebookApp.tokenのところでエラーが出てしまいます。そこをコメントアウトするとbuildは通ります。
誰かご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook

USER root
#for vscode extention
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
RUN code-server \
  --install-extension ms-python.python \
  --install-extension ms-ceintl.vscode-language-pack-ja

#for python libraries
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install seaborn && \
    pip install japanize-matplotlib

RUN sed -i 's/# c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'/c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'/' /home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
RUN sed -i 's/# c.NotebookApp.token = '<generated>'/c.NotebookApp.token = 'token'/' /home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
RUN sed -i 's/# c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = False/c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True/' /home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
RUN sed -i 's/# c.NotebookApp.port = 8888/c.NotebookApp.port = 8888/' /home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

ADD run.sh /opt/run.sh
RUN chmod 700 /opt/run.sh

WORKDIR /workdir
CMD /opt/run.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この sed では、たとえば `s/# c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'/c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'/` をひとつ目の文字列として渡そうとしているのだと思いますが、実際にはこの文字列の中にシングルクォート `'` が含まれているのに文字列自体もシングルクォートで囲おうとしているため意図しない結果になっています。

このため、`"s/# c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'/c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'/"` のようにダブルクォートで妥協するか、`'s/# c.NotebookApp.ip = '\''localhost'\''/c.NotebookApp.ip = '\''0.0.0.0'\''/'` のようにシングルクォートの外でエスケープ済みのシングルクォートを書くことで回避してください。

Answer (score 0):

sed コマンドのアドレス指定(`/regexp/`)+置換(`s///`)を用いて以下の様に書くこともできます。

```sh
sed -i -E '/^# c.NotebookApp.ip /{s/^# //;s/localhost/0.0.0.0/;}' jupyter_notebook_config.py
sed -i -E '/^# c.NotebookApp.token /{s/^# //;s/<generated>/token/;}' jupyter_notebook_config.py
sed -i -E '/^# c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf /{s/^# //;s/False/True/;}' jupyter_notebook_config.py
sed -i -E '/^# c.NotebookApp.port /s/^# //' jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

**実行結果**

```sh
$ cp -pv jupyter_notebook_config.py jupyter_notebook_config.py.org

## edit by sed command

$ diff -u jupyter_notebook_config.py.org jupyter_notebook_config.py
--- jupyter_notebook_config.py.org  1971-01-01 09:49:39.118837629 +0900
+++ jupyter_notebook_config.py  1971-01-01 09:49:28.514267925 +0900
@@ -223,7 +223,7 @@
 #  authentication and security checks, with the full knowledge of what that
 #  implies.
 #  Default: False
-# c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = False
+c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
 
 ## Whether to enable MathJax for typesetting math/TeX
 #  
@@ -282,7 +282,7 @@
 
 ## ノートブックサーバが待ち受ける IP アドレス。
 #  Default: 'localhost'
-# c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'
+c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
 
 ## Jinja environment に渡される追加の引数を指定します。
 #  Default: {}
@@ -406,7 +406,7 @@
 
 ## The port the notebook server will listen on (env: JUPYTER_PORT).
 #  Default: 8888
-# c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
+c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
 
 ## The number of additional ports to try if the specified port is not available
 #  (env: JUPYTER_PORT_RETRIES).
@@ -493,7 +493,7 @@
 #  Setting to an empty string disables authentication altogether, which is NOT
 #  RECOMMENDED.
 #  Default: '<generated>'
-# c.NotebookApp.token = '<generated>'
+c.NotebookApp.token = 'token'
```